# In how many ways can $3$ boys and $4$ girls be seated under the following conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Having an issue with a permutation question.

> $3$ boys $4$ girls need to sit down in a row

> (a) How many ways can you arrange them if there are no restrictions?

$7! = 5040$.     I think anyway!

> (b) How many ways can you arrange them if the girls have to sit together?

$(4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1) \times3 \times2 \times 1 = 144$ permutations. Not sure on this one. Do i count the boys as a seperate entity and only allow one permutation?

> (c) How many ways can you arrange them if no two girls can sit beside each other?

My thoughts on this are
$4\times3\times3\times2\times2\times1\times1$

I have put the numbers that i think represent the girls in *italics*

Thanks for any help!

Comment: sitting on a linear bench, or around a circular table? do you distinguish only between boys and girls, or also between each boy and each girl ?

Comment: That is actually a fantastic question. I assume a linear bench but its definately worth asking! Thanks for the input

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming by your answers that you are arranging these people side-by-side instead of circularly, and that you distinguish between different boys and girls.

**How many ways can you arrange them with no restrictions?**

You're correct, there are $7!$ ways to arrange them.

**How many ways can you arrange them if the girls have to sit next to each other?**

Then we can treat all the girls as though they are one entity, so there are $4!$ ways - three boys, and one "girl". The "girl", however, can be arranged in $4!$ ways. Thus there are $4! * 4! = 2 * 4!$ ways to arrange them.

**How many ways can you arrange them if no two girls can sit beside each other?**

There are four girls and three boys, so necessarily the arrangement looks like:

$$YXYXYXY$$

Where $X$ is a boy and $Y$ is a girl. There are $3!$ ways to arrange the boys, and $4!$ ways to arrange the girls, so the total number of arrangements is $3! * 4!$.

Comment: see my question above

Comment: Thanks for the taking the time to help. I can see where I was going wrong now! Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Just another quick question on this, If there are 3 girls, 4 boys and the girls have to sit beside eachother would I be right in saying.                   GBBBB = 5!                                                                                                 3! for the different way the girls can be arranged.                                    5! * 3! = 720 arrangements. Thanks

Comment: In the second question, $4!4! = (4!)^2$, not $2 \cdot 4!$.